# WPF ContentControl Content as ContentControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, nested, contentcontrol

Is it not possible to have multiple layers of UserControls containing ContentControl?

I am trying to create Views for different Models that are derived, so I'd like to eliminate the need to re-create the Views for each object type, and instead provide a ContentControl, or a ContentPresenter to inject the "rest of the view". However, I can only go one level deep with this method.

Here's a simplified example.(I've removed some of the xmlns). In my case, I'm working with significantly more complex Views, and trying to eliminate duplicate code in multiple places, concerned for changes later.

I have a Base UserControl, we'll call it UserControlLevel1

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContentControlNesting.UserControlLevel1"
             x:Name="userControlLevel1"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContentControlNesting">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="UserControlLevel1ContentTop"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=userControlLevel1, Path=ChildContent}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="UserControlLevel2ContentBottom"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

It has the following DependencyProperty on the UserControl

```
namespace ContentControlNesting
{
    public partial class UserControlLevel1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControlLevel1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ChildContent", typeof(UIElement), typeof(UserControlLevel1), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public UIElement ChildContent
        {
            get { return (UIElement)GetValue(ChildContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ChildContentProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

The ContentControl will be used in the following UserControl called UserControlLevel2. This UserControl works fine, just the way I would expect. Or rather UserControlLevel1 works properly within UserControlLevel2.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContentControlNesting.UserControlLevel2"
             x:Name="userControlLevel2"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContentControlNesting">
    <local:UserControlLevel1>
        <local:UserControlLevel1.ChildContent>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="UserControlLevel2ContentTop"/>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=userControlLevel2, Path=ChildContent}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="UserControlLevel2ContentBottom"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </local:UserControlLevel1.ChildContent>
    </local:UserControlLevel1>
</UserControl>
```

Likewise, it has a single DependencyProperty for the ContentControl on this UserControl like the first. I've also tried this with differently named DependencyProperties.

```
namespace ContentControlNesting
{
    public partial class UserControlLevel1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControlLevel1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ChildContent", typeof(UIElement), typeof(UserControlLevel1), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public UIElement ChildContent
        {
            get { return (UIElement)GetValue(ChildContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ChildContentProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, so at this point, everything seems to be working fine. I've added additional content inside of the ContentControl of UserControlLevel1, and I've added another ContentControl within my UserControlLevel2 UserControl.

The problem is when I try to introduce a 3rd Tier of either UserControl or my MainWindow. Anything I add to the ContentControl of UserControlLevel2 just does not appear.

```
<Window x:Class="ContentControlNesting.MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContentControlNesting"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="300">
    <local:UserControlLevel2>
        <local:UserControlLevel2.ChildContent>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Main Window Content Text"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </local:UserControlLevel2.ChildContent>
    </local:UserControlLevel2>
</Window>
```

Am I trying to do something that's not possible? Or am I doing something wrong with ContentControl and the DependencyProperties? Should I be looking at this with a different approach?

Comment: I stumbled upon this answer - stackoverflow.com/a/5758383/2777422 to a similar but different question. The needs were different, but the content in one of the answers seemed initially to point me in the right direction. It recommends using a ControlTemplate. My question is, why does this allow me to go more than 2 levels deep? Ultimately, this isn't the perfect answer either, as I loose Intellisense databinding and once I created some DependencyProperties to drive the text values in the UserControlLevel1 Textbloxs above, the default value doesn't show up in a ControlTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. The system cannot resolve the `ElementName` in the `Binding`. The solution is to use the relative binding. Just replace the following line in UserControlLevel2 and your are done:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=ChildContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControlLevel2}}}"/>
```

Comment: This appears to be working, though I will say with some caveats. If multiple instances of the user control are used, they do not update in the Designer initially, you must rebuild the Project / Solution to see the changes. Additionally, each tier of User Control must have the property named differently. When I went to add a relativesource to both Level 1 and Level 2, it gave me errors during design time, and threw an exception at runtime. I change the name of the Property to be unique per tier and it seems to work alright, albiet, I must perform a rebuild as mentioned to see any changes.